# Как можно извлечь строки из строковых массивов в отдельных ресурсах (например, файлах ***.xml)?

Tags: java

Как можно извлечь строки из строковых массивов в отдельных ресурсах (например, файлах ***.xml) на Java?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Для чего вам это?

Answer (score 0):

Я не полностью понял вопрос, но вам кажется надо использовать Scanner(для чтения файла) и PrintWriter(для того чтобы скопировать содержимое файла)